# Time complexity to compute the given solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying the leetcode Question -
Given an integer n, return all the structurally unique BST's (binary search trees), which has exactly n nodes of unique values from 1 to n. Return the answer in any order.
Constraints:
1 <= n <= 8
I have written the solution an it got accepted. I am finding it hard to compute the time complexity.

code is as follow

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    vector<TreeNode*> solve(int s, int e){
        
        vector<TreeNode*> v; 
        if(s > e){
            v.push_back(NULL); 
        }
        for(int i = s; i<=e; i++){
            vector<TreeNode*> l = solve(s,i-1); 
            vector<TreeNode*> r = solve(i+1,e); 
            for(auto j : l){
                TreeNode*left = j; 
                for(auto k : r){
                    TreeNode*right = k; 
                    TreeNode*node = new TreeNode(i); 
                    node->left = j; 
                    node->right = k; 
                    v.push_back(node); 
                }
            }
        }
        return v; 
        
    }
    
    vector<TreeNode*> generateTrees(int n) {
        
        return solve(1,n); 
        
    }
};
```

My observations -
No of recursive calls are - n
I find it of the order -
n *(2*(n^3)*n^2)

Comment: Try for various values of N, like 1, 10, 100, etc. and see what that curve looks like. Not sure why you're restricted to 1 through 8, as that's a trivial count.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: thanks for a quick response, would you be so kind to let me know - Isn't there a computing method to compute the time complexity for such type of solutions ?

Comment: You can approximate it by counting loops and such, but for a more exact method you need to actually time it. Since this has three loops, it looks roughly *O(N^3)* though that recursion complicates things as it is cubic as well. Remember *O* is extremely approximate, so you remove lesser terms and massively simplify it. This could be *O(N!)*. You need to test it.

Comment: I agree it has 3 loops, but what about the 2 recursive calls inside. 
(at the start of every iteration in the first for loop )

Comment: Test. It. Chart. The. Results. Please.

Comment: I have checked and found this 
(value of n ,iterations)
1  - > 1
3   ->  15
5   -> 190
8   -> 7832
doesn't looks like n^3

Comment: Is that 1=1, 3=15, 5=190? Having data is the first step. The next is to see what kind of curve that is. Looks like roughly *O(N^6)* or *O(N^7)* or so which is what we call in computer science "not great".

Comment: For a really rough approximation: log(7832)/log(8)

Comment: This question is particularly cruel since they don't tell you how deep that tree is, which seems to influence how much work the solver has to do *significantly*. You can only really guesstimate in very approximate terms here. The complexity is a function of tree depth.

Comment: Thanks to put some light on this.
 I am having an upcoming interview and wondering what order will I tell the time complexity of the solution is asked in an interview ( on white board)
I can approximate as max value of n in the given question is 8. I am thinking this from interview perspective.

Comment: The best way to prepare for those sorts of questions is to look at a lot of these types of problems, make your best guess, then do some actual testing to see what the result is. It's worth noting that a lot of these whiteboard questions are effectively nonsense, it's just this ridiculous ceremony, so you may need to know both the empirically correct answer, and the "generally accepted wisdom" answer as well.

Comment: got it. thanks a ton :)

Comment: The number of such trees grows exponentially with `n`, so an algorithm that enumerates all of them can't possibly be faster than exponential. Indeed, the number of trees with `n+1` nodes is at least twice that of trees with `n` nodes - at the very least, we can make `1` the root and put all the possible `n`-sized trees on the right, plus make `n+1` the root and put all the possible `n`-sized trees on the left. Therefore, the number of `n`-sized trees is no smaller than `2^n`

Comment: The answer will almost certainly be given in terms of Catalan Numbers.